# d3.js - scaling bubble chart app

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I have a bubble force chart application, and I've created various instances of it. However I can not seem to scale the bubbles in relation to the height/width of the svg.

http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/138/

I've placed an inverse on the heights/widths to alter the viewport - but it doesn't feel like the right approach to me. Does anyone have any experience as to how to correct this?

```
                    var inverseHeight = 1/h * 100000;
                    var inverseWidth = 1/w * 100000;


                    var svg = d3.select(selector)
                        .append("svg")
                            .attr("class", "bubblechart")
                            .attr("width", parseInt(w + padding,10))
                            .attr("height", parseInt(h + padding,10))
                            .attr('viewBox', "0 0 "+parseInt(inverseWidth,10)+" "+parseInt(inverseHeight,10))
                            .attr('perserveAspectRatio', "xMinYMid")
                        .append("g")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/4) + "," + (h/4) + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to scale the actual bubbles 
http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/143/

```
var scale = methods.width*.005;
```

Its producing an ideal effect - but the chart is not always central.

Comment: Does anyone have any insight? It will be very useful if someone has experience with this kind of thing.

Comment: Any suggestions on this - to configure the scale of the orbs correctly and have more control on their positions?